# How do you control the output format of a date when writing a CSV file with FileHelpers?

Tags: .net, csv, filehelpers

I'm using the **FileHelpers 2.0** library to write a CSV file using the `ClassBuilder` class to generate a record type.

My data contains dates and so I create a field of type `DateTime`, but when the file is generated the date values come out in the format `ddmmyyyy` rather than `dd/mm/yyyy` e.g. `28042000` instead of `28/04/2000`.

I've set the `DateFormat` property of the `CsvOptions` class to `"dd/MM/yyyy"` but it doesn't help.

Here is the code that generates the record type:

```
    private Type CreateRecordType()
    {
        int propertyIndex = 0;
        var csvOptions = new CsvOptions("Flat" + _report.RootType.Name, ',', Properties.Count)
                             {
                                 DateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
                             };
        var classBuilder = new CsvClassBuilder(csvOptions);

        foreach(var property in Properties)
        {
            var fieldBuilder = classBuilder.FieldByIndex(propertyIndex++);
            fieldBuilder.FieldName = property.Name;
            fieldBuilder.FieldType = property.Type.Name;
        }

        return classBuilder.CreateRecordClass();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you need to use the `Converter` property of the `FieldBuilder` class.

Adding the following block of code to my method allows me to customise the date format in the resulting CSV file.

```
if (property.Type == typeof(DateTime))
{
   fieldBuilder.Converter.Kind = ConverterKind.Date;
   fieldBuilder.Converter.Arg1 = "dd/MM/yyyy";
}
```